# Get list of column names having either object or categorical dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

My goal is to get a list object: `['assetCode', 'assetName']`, where the contents are the labels of a `Panda.series` that are retrieved based on more than one condition. I tried:

```
tmp3 = datatype[datatype == 'object' | datatype == 'category'].index # extract label from Pandas.series
```

This gives the error: `TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]`

However, while less elegant, I was able to find the following two working solutions:

```
tmp2 = datatype[datatype == 'object'].index # extract label from Pandas.series
tmp2[0]
'assetCode'


tmp1 = datatype[datatype == 'category'].index # extract label from Pandas.series
tmp1[0]
'assetName'
```

How do I combine these two strings into a list object? Is there a better way to achieve that goal than the way I am trying to do it?

Comment: it is due to operator precedence, you have to put a bracket between each conditions as the below answer shows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df

   A  B  C
0  8  4  2
1  8  8  6
2  8  5  2

datatype = df.dtypes
datatype

A      object
B    category
C       int64
dtype: object
```

---

It looks like you are trying to select object and categorical columns from some DataFrame (not shown here). To fix your code, use:

```
tmp3 = datatype[(datatype == 'object') | (datatype == 'category')].index.tolist()
tmp3
#  ['A', 'B']
```

Since bitwise operators have higher precedence, you will need to use parentheses before ORing the masks. After that, indexing works fine.

To get a list, call `.index.tolist()`.

---

Another solution is `select_dtypes`:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'category'])

   A  B
0  8  4
1  8  8
2  8  5

df.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'category']).columns
# ['A', 'B']
```

This circumvents the need for an intermediate `datatype` series.